# Strip whitespaces in AWK

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have tried to remove all the white spaces but it's not taking it.

```
awk -F, -v OFS=", " 'NR==1 {
        print $0,"FILENAME,DATE_LOADED,TEST";
        next
      }
      {                              
        line=$0
        key=echo "${11//[[:space:]]/}" "${12//[[:space:]]/}" "${57//[[:space:]]/}"
        key | getline
        k=$0
        cmd="md5 <<<"k
        cmd | getline
        md5sum=$0
        print line, ENVIRON["FILE"], ENVIRON["ISODATE"], md5sum
}' $FILE > $NAME"_ready.csv"
```

If I try this it throws errors. I tried all options and really at a loss here.

```
key=echo $11$12$57 | tr -d
```

Comment: 1. Can you show example some input data and expected output? 2. Does it have to be awk? Would you be happy some shell or one-line perl?

Comment: A simple `echo "abc def" | tr -d ' '` works fine too.

Comment: @mvp it's inside a bash file and not sure i call perl inside the awk function.

Answer (score 4):

```
awk '{gsub(" +","");print $0}' test.text
```

If you want only awk based solution then this one liner will remove all the spaces from the file.

Comment: Sorry this is not working. 

      key=awk '{gsub(" +","");print $11}'

I need to remove the spaces only from the var key

Comment: please provide sample input and output

Comment: $12='James M' $13='n brooks rd' $57='los angeles' 
these are columns loaded from the csv and change per row. 
this i need to hash to a md5 without spaces. 
So this is this part of the function `key=echo "${11//[[:space:]]/}" "${12//[[:space:]]/}" "${57//[[:space:]]/}"
        key | getline
        k=$0
        cmd="md5 <<<"k`